# how to draw curve edge between nodes more beautiful?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

[image: screenshot of output]

I want to draw pre/post-order threaded binary tree like the in-order threaded binary tree's picture above(from wiki threaded binary tree page).

I tried the code below, however the edges **C->B, E->F, H->G** are quite different from origin picture. I read the tkz&pgf manual, but not find some method to make the edges as beautiful as origin picture.

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress,xcolor=x11names,UTF8, aspectratio=169,border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
% \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
%\setCJKmainfont{微软雅黑}
\setCJKmainfont{Hei}

\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"          % Following set to break line automatically.
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 1pt plus 1pt 

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning,trees,calc,positioning}
\tikzset{
    every picture/.style={
        semithick,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth',node distance=4em,
        every state/.style={minimum size=2em,align=center},
        accepting/.style={double distance=.1em,outer sep=\pgflinewidth}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[smooth]

    \node[state]   (F)                                {$F$};

    \node[state]   (B)  [below left=2em and 2.5em of F]  {$B$};
    \node[state]   (G)  [below right=2em and 2.5em of F]  {$G$};

    \node[state]   (A)  [below left=1.5em and 1em of B]  {$A$};
    \node[state]   (D)  [below right=1.5em and 1em of B]  {$D$};
    \node[state]   (I)  [below right=1.5em and 1em of G]  {$I$};

    \node[state]   (C)  [below left=1.5em and 0.6em of D]  {$C$};
    \node[state]   (E)  [below right=1.5em and 0.6em of D]  {$E$};
    \node[state]   (H)  [below left=1.5em and 0.6em of I]  {$H$};

    \path[->]   (F) edge              (B)
                (F) edge              (G)

                (B) edge              (A)
                (B) edge              (D)
                (G) edge              (I)

                (D) edge              (C)
                (D) edge              (E)
                (I) edge               (H)

                (A) edge [->,dashed, out=-60,in=-110]            (B)
                (C) edge [->,dashed, out=-130,in=-85,looseness=1.5]           (B)
                (C) edge [->,dashed, out=-50,in=-100,looseness=1.5]           (D)
            (E) edge [->,dashed, out=-120,in=-80,looseness=1.5]           (D)
                (E) edge [->,dashed, out=-50,in=-100]           (F)
            (G) edge [->,dashed, out=-120,in=-70]           (F)
            (H) edge [->,dashed, out=-120,in=-95,looseness=1.5]           (G)
            (H) edge [->,dashed, out=-60,in=-100,looseness=1.5]           (I)
            ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I just want to know how to draw curve edges like the red lines:

[image]

Comment: seems using coordinates of several points can make it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At page 280 of the [Tikz & PGF manual](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) you can find a lot of options for `to[]` command.
In particular, `controls=⟨coordinate⟩ and ⟨coordinate⟩` adds to your path more points of control.

You can try the following

```
\path[->,green]
  (C) edge [->,dashed, out=-130,in=-85,looseness=1.5,controls=+(200:1.5) and +(-40:1)] (B)    
  (E) edge [->,dashed, out=-70,in=-100,controls=+(-30:1.7) and +(240:1.3)] (F)
  (H) edge [->,dashed, out=-120,in=-95,looseness=1.5,controls=+(240:1.5) and +(260:.7)]  (G);
```

where the controls are given by polar coordinates `(angle:radius)` relative respectively to the first end the second node of the edge.

[image]

Enjoy yourself to find the best path!

Answer (score 0):

More freedom with bezier curves en lieu de edges:

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress,xcolor=x11names,UTF8, aspectratio=169,border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
% \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{xeCJK}
%%\setCJKmainfont{微软雅黑}
%\setCJKmainfont{Hei}
%
%\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"          % Following set to break line automatically.
%\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 1pt plus 1pt 

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning,trees,calc,positioning,topaths}
\tikzset{
    every picture/.style={
        semithick,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth',node distance=4em,
        every state/.style={minimum size=2em,align=center},
        accepting/.style={double distance=.1em,outer sep=\pgflinewidth}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[smooth]

    \node[state]   (F)                                {$F$};

    \node[state]   (B)  [below left=2em and 2.5em of F]  {$B$};
    \node[state]   (G)  [below right=2em and 2.5em of F]  {$G$};

    \node[state]   (A)  [below left=1.5em and 1em of B]  {$A$};
    \node[state]   (D)  [below right=1.5em and 1em of B]  {$D$};
    \node[state]   (I)  [below right=1.5em and 1em of G]  {$I$};

    \node[state]   (C)  [below left=1.5em and 0.6em of D]  {$C$};
    \node[state]   (E)  [below right=1.5em and 0.6em of D]  {$E$};
    \node[state]   (H)  [below left=1.5em and 0.6em of I]  {$H$};

    \draw[->,dashed] (H.south west) .. controls (0.5,-3.7) and (1.5,-2.7) .. (G.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```